# Setting up a load balancer for HA rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, haproxy, kombu

I am trying to set up a high availability RabbitMQ cluster with mirrored queues.
Actually, I have set that up and that was the easy part. Now comes the part where my producers and consumers need to access the cluster, or specifically, the master node, whichever that might be at the time. I am trying to set up HAproxy for that but I have some questions pertaining to how it would work.
Specifically, HAproxy is not being used here as a balancer as it is to do health checks. Suppose the original master goes down and the oldest surviving slave is promoted to new master? How can HAproxy be set up the detect who this is and route all connections to the new master?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure HAProxy to do this. Check out [this](http://www.rabbitmq.com/pacemaker.html) complete guide from RabbitMQ.

If you want to achieve real load balancing with RabbitMQ in a HA-configuration, [this](http://insidethecpu.com/2014/11/17/load-balancing-a-rabbitmq-cluster/) might also interest you.